# Why isn't this getting the stuff between brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking at

```
var r = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}");
var m = r.Match("{abc}");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

and it's getting me `"{abc}"` whereas I expected it to get the stuff in between brackets, `"abc"`. Isn't that the `Value`?

Also, I don't know if this is possible, but I want to get the outermost paranthesis in the case that they are nested, e.g.

`"{{abc}"` --> `"{abc"`

Comment: general speaking, regexs which return capture groups will return the entire string that caused a match/capture as their first/0th argument in the var containing the capture data. check `groups[1]` instead.

Comment: Although the regex is not the issue here, the standard way to capture stuff between brackets is `"\{[^}]\}"`, assuming no escaped closing brackets within brackets.

Comment: [Match.Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object (the element at index 0) returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern"...

Answer (score 3):

> it's getting me "{abc}" whereas I expected it to get the stuff in between brackets, "abc". Isn't that the Value?

No, look at `Groups[1]` which is the first match capture instead, while `Groups[0]` is the whole match.

The match capture is what is between the `(...)` in a regex match and those are numbered in successive order from 1 to n. While the other items are **matched** *but not captured* and found in the whole match at index 0.

---

> "{{abc}" --> "{abc"

Try `{+([^}]+)}` as a pattern for the `+` next to the `{` tells the regex parser to find 1 or more of `{`.

---

Note sometimes one doesn't want to deal with match captures indexes, then one can use *named match captures* such as this literal example:

`{+(?<TextBetweenTheBrackets>[^}]+)}`

and then extract the value between the brackets as

`Groups["TextBetweenTheBrackets"].value`